# Use jmp instruction to a non-constant TSS segment

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, kernel, gnu-assembler

[JMP instruction referece.](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html)

According to the documentation, we can perform `jmp` to a constant far segment:

```
jmp 0x18:00
```

Here, `0x18` is a valid segment selector in a GDT, Global Descriptor Table.

`jmp` can be used with a segment register that contains a valid GDT entry, that is a code/data segment descriptor:

```
mov es, 0x18
jmp es:0x0
```

Here, `0x18` is a TSS (Task State Segment) descriptor that when jumping to, CPU performs a task switch that automatically saves its state into the current TSS, and then populate with the state saved in the new TSS.

However, TSS is a system segment descriptor, and therefore cannot be loaded into any of the segment register (as suggested by Intel document). Then how, can I jump to a task at runtime with dynamically allocated TSS?

The only way I can think of is to use the `iret` instruction, but I feel it like a hack, as I need to modify the link field, and then set the NT bit in EFLAGS to perform back link task switching.

Comment: But `ltr` does not cause a task switch, that is the current state is automatically saved. But I guess I will give it a try to switch to a new task (non-interrupt task; interrupt handlers as tasks are already working), then workaround this limitation later.

Comment: I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't also use a JMP to a memory reference as operand. The memory operand would point to a memory address containing the selector/offset. That memory address can be modified at runtime

Comment: Like this: `jmp [mem1]:[mem2]`? But the assembler refuses to allow non-constant segment. The only memory operand it allows is `jmp [seg:eip]`, but then it means the memory location is fetched from a far address just to perform a near call.

Comment: I already tried it, and it retrieves the address but then perform a near jmp/call. Am I missing something? Maybe I will try again before the `iret` hack.

Comment: So, you mean `jmp 0xabcd:0x0`, where `0xabcd` holds the TSS selector or just plain TSS works? I already got jumping to a constant TSS selector work, e.g. `jmp 0x18:0x0`, where 0x18 is a segment selector in the GDT.

Comment: And memory references will be denoted by square brackets `[` `]`

Comment: So, you meant that `jmp [0xabcd:0x0]`, where `0xabcd` holds the TSS, then it works? I will try it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only can't you load ES with a TSS selector, the instruction `jmp es:0x0` is also invalid.  There's no instruction that moves a segment register to another segment register (eg. ES to CS). There's also no instruction that will load CS from a general register. As Margaret Bloom's answer shows you'll need load CS with JMP instruction that takes a memory operand, specifically one that takes a far pointer as a memory operand so you get a far jump instruction that sets CS.

As far as implementing this it would make sense to put this far pointer in your task structure, the structure where you place the task's TSS and other task specific information.  For example to switch tasks you could use code like this:

```
struct task {
    struct {
        unsigned offset;
        unsigned short selector;
    } far_jmp_ptr;
    struct tss tss;
    // ...
};

void
switch_tasks(struct task *new_task) {
    asm("jmp FAR PTR %0" : : "m" (new_task->far_jmp_ptr));
}
```

The code assumes a "task structure" with a far pointer that contains the allocated TSS selector for the task (the offset part is ignored).

Technically, you can also jump to a task by using an LTR instruction followed by a JMP instruction. This changes the task without performing a task switch, so no registers (other than TR, CS:EIP and any other registers you explicitly change) are affected. For example:

```
mov  esi, [new_task]
ltr  [esi + TASK_FAR_JMP_PTR + 4]
jmp  [esi + TASK_TSS + TSS_EIP]
```

This would only be practical if the new task is running at ring 0 and either is just starting or was stopped at a known point where it didn't need its registers restored.  In particular this is how you might start an initial kernel task (or the only task in a single TSS operating system.)

Note that most operating systems only use one TSS for all tasks, and so don't use the task switching mechanism provided by the CPU. For 64-bit operating systems this is required, as task switching isn't supported in long mode.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. About the form `jmp es:0x0`, GAS does not reject it. This is the generated code from that sytnax: `26 ff 25 00 00 00 00    jmp    *%es:0x0` (objdump output).

Comment: @Amumu Your post didn't use GAS's AT&T syntax, so my answer and Margaret Blooms used NASM syntax, which is the syntax the assembly code in your post most closely resembles. GAS generated a near indirect jmp with loads EIP with the 32-bit value stored at ES:0 and doesn't change CS (or the task) at all.

Comment: Well I used GAS but set it to Intel syntax.

Comment: @Amumu I've updated my first example to use GCC inline assembly using MASM-style syntax.

Comment: adding PTR seems to make GCC generates `ljmp` instruction now. Thanks. is there a reference to this PTR syntax?

Answer (score 6):

```
push WORD <TSS_selector>
push DWORD 0
jmp FAR [esp]
```

Assuming 32-bit code and an usable stack.
This will leave the stack unbalanced and unaligned in the calling thread, you may want to use a dedicated memory location:

```
mov WORD [tss_pointer + 4], <TSS_selector>
jmp FAR [tss_pointer]

tss_pointer dd 0, dw 0
```

Comment: Depending on your context you can reduce this code by using red stack:  cli ; mov word [esp + 2], TSS_selector ; mov dword [esp + 6], 0 sti ; jmp far [esp + 6]. In user mode omit the cli and sti instructions (but your code will crash if a debugger is attached). This code depends on the obscure fact that an interrupt cannot cut in immediately after the sti instruction but only one instruction after.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It quickly gave me initial idea to detect where I was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The suggested answers here are correct, but there's a missing piece: the syntax suggested does not generate a long jump. I did as [Margaret Bloom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40513911/496700)
suggested, but it didn't work. There must be something wrong with my code, since I know she gave me the right answer, as others also suggest the same thing. Looking at GDB, when I applied the above syntax:

```
asm("pushw 0xa0");
asm("pushd 0x0");
asm("jmp  far [esp]");
```

(The above syntax is inline assembly, GCC style)

Looking at GDB, `jmp far` is generated as:

```
0x30a9 <task1_start+1>  mov    ebp,esp
0x30ab <task1_start+3>  pushw  0xa0
0x30af <task1_start+7>  push   0x0
0x30b1 <task1_start+9>  jmp    DWORD PTR [esp+0xff06]
```

Clearly, `[esp + 0xff06]` does not look very far to me. It's a near jump, with offset from the `esp`. More evidently, from the output of `objdump`:

```
000030a8 <task1_start>:
    30a8:       55                      push   %ebp
    30a9:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
    30ab:       66 68 a0 00             pushw  $0xa0
    30af:       6a 00                   push   $0x0
    30b1:       ff a4 24 06 ff 00 00    jmp    *0xff06(%esp)
    30b8:       90                      nop
    30b9:       5d                      pop    %ebp
    30ba:       c3                      ret
```

Notice the opcode at `0x30ab`, that corresponds to the `jmp` instruction. Looking at the Intel manual, that opcode for a near jump:

- `0xff` stands for `jmp` instruction.
- `0xa4` is the ModR/M byte for `[--][--] + disp32` effective address for `esp`. This means, a SiB byte is required, which is the offset. (reference: Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte)
- `0x24` is the `SiB` byte stands for ESP, but without any scaling (the value is `none`), effectively, keep it the same. (reference: Table 2-3. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the SIB Byte).

The above generated `jmp` corresponds to `FF /4` opcode (reference: [jmp instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html)), which means a near jump, since the generated ModR/M byte is `0xa4`. The correct opcode for far jump is `FF /5`.

Clearly, I must do something for the assembler to generate a long jump. So, it turned out, it is easy to fix using `ljmp` instruction instead of `jmp far` syntax like so:

```
ljmp [esp]
```

After that, we got properly generated code:

```
00003088 <task1_start>:
    3088:       55                      push   %ebp
    3089:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
    308b:       66 68 a0 00             pushw  $0xa0
    308f:       6a 00                   push   $0x0
    3091:       ff 2c 24                ljmp   *(%esp)
    3094:       90                      nop
    3095:       5d                      pop    %ebp
    3096:       c3                      ret
```

In the above, `ljmp` is generated:

- `0xff` is the opcode for `jmp`, the same. `ljmp` is just a particular syntax used by GAS (GNU Assembler) to generate `FF /5` opcode.
- `0x2c` is the ModR/M byte for `[--][--]` (no displacement), but at the column `5` in table 2-2. Which means, this opcode is truly `FF /5`.
- `0x24` is the same for near jump, which means no scaling.

And this is the actual code seen by GDB:

```
0x308b <task1_start+3>  pushw  0xa0           
0x308f <task1_start+7>  push   0x0            
0x3091 <task1_start+9>  jmp    FWORD PTR [esp]
```

Now, `FWORD` is something new but at least it does not add random displacement anymore. And indeed, the task is switched correctly to `0xa0`.

Thanks for your suggestions, everyone. Without it, I could've never investigated this out.

Comment: There's a number of problems with your answer. You can't use GCC style inline assembly like that. You need to do everything in one statement, since the compiler can insert other instructions in between. You used a 16-bit push which misaligned the stack. You used NASM syntax instead of GAS's version MASM syntax, that's why `jmp far [esp]` didn't work.

Comment: I set this option: `-masm=intel`, so GCC is using intel. Yes, the compiler can insert instructions in between. However, it's just a possibility and as far as the actual generated code goes, no extra code was inserted in between those push and jump instructions. As for 16 bit push, it's just a demonstration followed by the answer from Margaret. I will fix to use memory instead. I was using the stack just to verify if it works.

Comment: The other problem with your inline assembly statement is that the old task will resume at the instruction after the far jump with the registers restored to what they were before the jump. That means it'll crash as the far address pushed on the stack will still be there.

Comment: Ah thanks. I will need to put additional inline asm code to clear the stack for a proper return address.